# Why printing a scapy.layers.l2.Ether object using Python 2 I obtain the expected result while printing it using Python 3 I obtain this strange output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scapy

I am an absolute beginner with **Python** and I am finding the following strange behavior in my program if I execute it using **Python 3** instead using **Python 2**.

I will try to explain the situation in details.

I have these 2 versions of Python installed on my machine:

- **Python 2.7.17**
- **Python 3.7.7**

Then I have this script using **Scapy**:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

# INSTALL THE FOLLOWING PYTHON MODULES:
# - pip3 install scapy
# - pip3 install scapy_http

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

#
def sniff(interface):
    # iface: specify the interface used to sniff on.
    # store: I tell scapy to not store packets in memory.
    # prn: allows to specify a callback function (a function that is call every time that the sniff() function sniff
    #      a packet.
    # OPTIONAL FILTERS: uses to specifies filters packets using "BPF syntax"
    #         SOME FILTER EXAMPLES:
    #           - udp: filter UDP packets
    #           - arp: filter ARP packets
    #           - tcp: filter TCP packets
    #           - port 21: filter packets on a specific port
    # DOCUMENTATION LINK: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html
    #scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet, filter=80)
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    #print(packet)
    # Check if our packet has HTTP layer. If our packet has the HTTP layer and it is HTTPRequest.
    # In this way I am excluding some garbage information in which I am not interested into.
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        print(packet)
        print("-------------------------------------")
        #print(packet.decode("utf-8"))
        print(type(packet))


sniff("eth0")
```

This script implement a simple traffic sniffer over HTTP protocol.

The version of **scapy** used by **Python 2** should be this one:

```
root@kali:~/Documents/PycharmWS/packet_sniffer# pip show scapy
Name: scapy
Version: 2.4.3
Summary: Scapy: interactive packet manipulation tool
Home-page: https://scapy.net
Author: Philippe BIONDI
Author-email: phil(at)secdev.org
License: GPLv2
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

The version of **scapy** used by **Python 3** should be this one:

```
root@kali:~/Documents/PycharmWS/packet_sniffer# pip3 show scapy
Name: scapy
Version: 2.4.3
Summary: Scapy: interactive packet manipulation tool
Home-page: https://scapy.net
Author: Philippe BIONDI
Author-email: phil(at)secdev.org
License: GPLv2
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

So basically the version is the same: **2.4.3** and should works in the same way (it's just taken from different directories based on the Python version).

The strange behavior happens when this function print the packet content:

```
def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    #print(packet)
    # Check if our packet has HTTP layer. If our packet has the HTTP layer and it is HTTPRequest.
    # In this way I am excluding some garbage information in which I am not interested into.
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        print(packet)
        print("-------------------------------------")
        #print(packet.decode("utf-8"))
        print(type(packet))
```

Here happens a strange thing:

Executing the script with **Python 2.7.17** I obtain the expected output:

```
root@kali:~/Documents/PycharmWS/packet_sniffer# python packet_sniffer.py 
jA">�P▒���NPOST / HTTP/1.1�
Host: ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/ocsp-request
Content-Length: 85
Connection: keep-alive

0S0Q0O0M0K0     +▒~�j�r����� dl�-`]�Jjc}ݺ��9��Ee�������� *y��8:�3zyJ�
```

While exectugint the script with **Python 3.7.7** I obtain this strange encoded output:

```
root@kali:~/Documents/PycharmWS/packet_sniffer# python3 packet_sniffer.py 
b'\x00PV\xfd\xa9B\x00PV)\x97\xc7\x08\x00E\x00\x01\xa7\xe8R@\x00@\x06\x9fI\xc0\xa8\xdf\x85\x97\x1dzi\xbaL\x00P\xc3\rj\x11A">\xd1P\x18\xfa\xf0\xb3N\x00\x00POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nContent-Type: application/ocsp-request\r\nContent-Length: 85\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n0S0Q0O0M0K0\t\x06\x05+\x0e\x03\x02\x1a\x05\x00\x04\x14~\xe6j\xe7r\x9a\xb3\xfc\xf8\xa2 dl\x16\xa1-`q\x08]\x04\x14\xa8Jjc\x04}\xdd\xba\xe6\xd19\xb7\xa6Ee\xef\xf3\xa8\xec\xa1\x02\x12\x03\x16\xe6\x87\xfc *y\xc1\xe48:\xdf3zyJ\xa4'
```

**NOTE: Originally I suspected that this was the output of a byte array (because it start with **b** but it is not, I printed the type of the **packet** variable using:

```
print(type(packet))
```

and the object type is:

```
<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Ether'>
```

So I suspected that this **scapy.layers.l2.Ether** contains a **bytearray** object that is print in this way or something like this.

Anyway, this should be the **scapy.layers.l2.Ether** code retrieved by the folder where pip installed it:

```
class Ether(Packet):
    name = "Ethernet"
    fields_desc = [DestMACField("dst"),
                   SourceMACField("src"),
                   XShortEnumField("type", 0x9000, ETHER_TYPES)]
    __slots__ = ["_defrag_pos"]

    def hashret(self):
        return struct.pack("H", self.type) + self.payload.hashret()

    def answers(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Ether):
            if self.type == other.type:
                return self.payload.answers(other.payload)
        return 0

    def mysummary(self):
        return self.sprintf("%src% > %dst% (%type%)")

    @classmethod
    def dispatch_hook(cls, _pkt=None, *args, **kargs):
        if _pkt and len(_pkt) >= 14:
            if struct.unpack("!H", _pkt[12:14])[0] <= 1500:
                return Dot3
        return cls
```

Why when I print this object using **Python 2** I obtain the expected output but printing it using **Python 3** I am obtaining this strange "ecrypted" output? What am I missing? There is a way to correctly print this output using Python 3? 
I know that I can use:

```
packet.show()
```

instead

```
print(packet)
```

but I have to use this **print(packet)** because I am following a tutorial that use this specific output to parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
print(bytes(packet).decode(errors="backslashreplace"))
```

Though Python3 uses bytes for a good reason

Comment: It seems to works fine !!! But what exactly does this line of code? I think that it cart to bytes and then decode. But I am not understandig why a packet object having **scapy.layers.l2.Ether** as type is printed as a bytes using Phyton 3. I desire to understand why. What is the exact logic?

Comment: A packet is always bytes on the network. Python 2 bytes is basically a plain string whereas python 3 has proper bytes. When using a string, you can see that all the characters that are not usual are displayed as �. Python 3 does not try to display them therefore keeps the `\x00` format, which corresponds to a byte.